# Detecting reflexes with apple smartwatch

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I want to ask whether it is possible to detect reflexes (fast movements) from the user with the apple smartwatch. Is it done by core motion? 
Is there some reference code to get a grasp how to implement this functionality?

I hope that anyone can help out. Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe you could start with [this doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/getting_raw_accelerometer_events?language=objc).

Comment: @ReinhardMänner: Can you imagine the accelerometer data can come closer to this functionality? Sorry, I am a beginner in this field.

Comment: I am sorry, I have never used the accelerometer. It was just a hint...

Answer (score 1):

You shall use **Core Motion** to achieve that.
Apple provides watchOS 3 [SwingWatch sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/SwingWatch/Introduction/Intro.html) demonstrating how to use `CMMotionManager()` and `startDeviceMotionUpdates(to:)` to count swings in a racquet sport.

Their code demonstrates how to detect the direction of a one-second interval of motion, although you may have to tweak the thresholds to account for the characteristics of the motion you want to track.
There's also an [WWDC video Health and Fitness with Core Motion](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/713/)

You may also find this article helpful:
[Introduction to Apple WatchKit with Core Motion — Tracking Jumping Jacks](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/introduction-to-apple-watchkit-with-core-motion-tracking-jumping-jacks-259ee80d1210)